# Issue with displaying collection of items in MutliSelectComboBox after saving with EF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, multi-select

I am creating a multiselect `Combobox` that allows a user to select multiple items from a `combobox`. So far I have achieved this by using an `ObservableCollection<string>`. I want to be able to save this collection using `EntityFramework model` which I have managed to do, like

Constructor;

```
public EmployeeViewModel(DataObjects.Employee e) //Constructor that takes in an employee from EF
        : base("")
    {
        //BenefitsProvided = e.BenefitsProvided; //What I did previously. BenefitsProvided is the field in employee table.

        _benefits = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        string[] benefit = e.BenefitsProvided.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach (var str in benefit)
        {
            _benefits.Add(str);
        }  
    }
```

On first startup, I get a list that does allow me to see a nice list of items, of which I am able to select as many as I want. But, When I try to edit the items, within the `ComboBox` it displays this;

Before;

[image]

After saving;

[image]

[This Link contains my ViewModel and Bindable list](https://gist.github.com/gregorybmclub/56ea2079f8e257626c45)

Binding;

```
 <src:MultiComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9"
                         SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         DisplaySeparator=", "
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Benefits}"
                         SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedBenefits}">
 </src:MultiComboBox>
```

What I tried is rather then taking a a `ObservableCollection<String>` took in a `ObservableCollection<OfAClass>` like so;

```
public class CurrentBenefits
{
    private string[] _Allowed = new string[] {"items", "..."};
    public string[] Allowed 
    { 
        get { return _Allowed; }
        set { _Allowed = value; }
    }
}
```

But when doing so, and changing the `<string>` to the `<CurrentBenefit>` it throws this exception around the constructor;

*Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to '...CurrentBenefits'*

*Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<...CurrentBenefits>.Add(...CurrentBenefits)' has some invalid arguments*

Could anyone help or advice what I should do to solve this issue that I have? Thanks in advance :).

*Edit:*
Also, sorry for such a long question.

Comment: Are you rebinding the ComboBox, after saving?

Comment: This is my binding (sorry forgot to add it) `<src:MultiComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Benefits}" SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedBenefits}">
 </src:MultiComboBox>`

Comment: I think you can get around this, by binding only at runtime with your list, and after saving re-binding.

This is a similar problem to yours : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297034/setting-binding-in-wpf-control-correctly

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for that link. I tried something similar within my xaml `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>` but when doing so, items seem to be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through my work, and with the wonderful help from [Maverik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504757/maverik) from [The WPF Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf), it was to do with my repository.

Originally, inserting and updating items within the repository was done so, like so;

```
emp.BenefitsProvided = e.Benefits.ToList().ToString();
```

Then it was changed to this;

```
emp.BenefitsProvided = string.Join(", ", e.SelectedBenefits);
```

It saved perfectly and enabled the user to see what they have added :).

As it was a `collection`, I also had to change it within my `ListView` to display the items like so;

```
 <GridViewColumn Header="BenefitsProvided" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ListView Height="24"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Benefits}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
 </GridViewColumn>
```